# How to clear memory after running cell in IPython notebook

Tags: python, memory-management, jupyter-notebook, out-of-memory, ipython

I run a cell in my IPython notebook and python3's memory usage goes up by ~100MB. After I run it again, python3's memory usage again goes up by ~100MB. After a few runs, my computer has run out of memory and programs are crashing.

I can fix this by resetting the IPython kernel, but then I lose the state of my entire notebook. Is there a way to clear the memory used by that particular cell when I re-run the cell, so that old runs don't just accumulate until my computer crashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `import gc; gc.collect()` to the beginning of my cell solves the issue.

Comment: I have seen people doing this but I don't get why it works. Python (CPython to be precise) should remove each variable from memory as soon as the last reference to it is removed. Since it's a Jupyter notebook all the variables are global. So why is anything deleted when running `gc.collect()`?